# How to correctly read hard drive partitions?

Tags: c, windows, borland-c++

I need to read all 4 hard drive partitions and display them on the screen.

Everything is fine with the output, but there is a problem with reading the partitions themselves. I don’t understand what to change - the head, cylinder or sector. I tried changing all these values ​​and something is always read, which is why I don't really understand whether I read everything correctly.

The program is written in C using Borland C++ (TurboC). I work in Windows 98.

What information needs to be displayed about the section:

```
Offset Length Contents
+0      1       Boot Flag- boot flag: 0=not active, 80h=active.
+1      1       Begin Hd - start of section: head (side) number.
+2      2       Begin Sec/Cyl – start of section: sector/cylinder. 
+4      1       System Code – file system code.
+5      1       Ending Hd – end of section: head number. 
+6      2       Ending Sec/Cyl – end of section: sector/cylinder of the last sector. 
+8      4       Starting Sector – logical number of the starting sector of the partition (address in
                LBA system). 
+0Ch    4       Num Sectors – partition size (number of sectors)
```

Program code:

```c
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//#define NUM_PARTITIONS 4

unsigned char buf[512];

int read_mbr() {
    union REGS in, out;
    struct SREGS sr;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (; i < 64; i += 16, j++) {
        sr.es = FP_SEG(buf + i);
        in.x.bx = FP_OFF(buf + i);

        in.h.ah = 0x02;
        in.h.al = 1;
        in.h.dl = 0x80 + j;
        in.h.dh = 0;
        in.h.cl = 1;
        in.h.ch = 0;

        int86x(0x13, &in, &out, &sr);

        if (out.x.cflag || out.h.ah)
            return 1;

        printf("%d", j);
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_count_partitions() {                                         
    int numPartitions = 0;
    int i = 0x1BE;

    for (; i <= 0x1EE; i += 16) {
        numPartitions++;
    }

    return numPartitions;
}

void extract_partition_info(int partition_number) {
    unsigned char beginHd = buf[1];
    unsigned short beginSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(buf + 2));

    // Print the extracted partition information
    printf("Partition %d:\n", partition_number);
    printf("Begin Hd: %u\n", beginHd);
    printf("Begin Sec/Cyl: %u\n", beginSecCyl);
}

void print_partition_info(unsigned char* partition_entry, int partition_number) {
    unsigned char bootFlag = partition_entry[0];
    unsigned char beginHd = partition_entry[1];
    unsigned short beginSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(partition_entry + 2));
    unsigned char systemCode = partition_entry[4];
    unsigned char endingHd = partition_entry[5];
    unsigned short endingSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(partition_entry + 6));
    unsigned int startingSector = *((unsigned int*)(partition_entry + 8));
    unsigned int numSectors = *((unsigned int*)(partition_entry + 0x0C));

    printf("Partition %d:\n", partition_number);
    printf("Boot Flag: 0x%02X\n", bootFlag);
    printf("Begin Hd: %u\n", beginHd);
    printf("Begin Sec/Cyl: %u\n", beginSecCyl);
    printf("System Code: 0x%02X\n", systemCode);
    printf("Ending Hd: %u\n", endingHd);
    printf("Ending Sec/Cyl: %u\n", endingSecCyl);
    printf("Starting Sector (LBA): %u\n", startingSector);
    printf("Number of Sectors: %u\n", numSectors);
    printf("Root Boot Sector Address (LBA): %u\n", startingSector);
}

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    clrscr();

    if (read_mbr())
        printf("Error reading sector\n");
    else
        printf("Sector read successfully\n");

    printf("Number of sections: %d\n", get_count_partitions());
    extract_partition_info(1);

    getch();
    clrscr();

    for(;j < 512; j++)
        printf("%d",(int)buf[j]);
    getch();

    for (; i < 64; i += 16){
        clrscr();
        print_partition_info(&buf[i], (i/16 + 1));
        getch();
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which oprating system do you run your program on? On most modern systems (Windows 11, 10, 8, 7, Vista, XP etc.), direct disk access (int86x(0x13, ...)) doesn't work. You have to use a different API.

Comment: You are assuming your computer has a BIOS instead of EFI, your disk has CHS instead of LBA, your partition table is DOS instead of GPT, and you are running in 16-bit real mode?

Comment: You need to make sure the endianness of your system matches the endianness of the disk data too.

Comment: @pts it is Windows 98.

Comment: On Windows 98 it may still work, a quick web search didn't reveal it. Try to run rhe program in DOS mode. Get and pring the error code.

Comment: _"BorlandC++(TurboC)"_ ? It can't be both.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually the old Turbo C++ compilers came with the C compiler built in and picked language based on .cpp vs .c extension.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The source file in the question compiles with both Borland C++ and Turbo C++ compilers for DOS, both as a C source and a C++ source. The difference between these compilers doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: @Влад -- file system is FAT32 right?